# Sinatra, Mongoid ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, rake

I am trying to create a create_indexes rake task for creating indexes for MongoDb records in my application.
I have Rakefile in the top directory of my application, with the following code.

```
require "./app"
set :database_file, "./config/mongoid.yml"
Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r}
```

I have create a db.rake file in the lib/tasks folder in my app

```
namespace :db do
task :create_indexes => :environment do
#
    begin
        Rails.application.eager_load!
    rescue Object => e
    end
#
    begin
        Bundler.require(:default, :assets, 'production')
    rescue Object => e
    end
#
    to_index_models = [] 

    ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) do |object|
        begin
            to_index_models.push(object) if object.respond_to?(:create_indexes)
        rescue Object => e
            warn "failed on: #{ object }.respond_to?(:create_indexes)"
        end
    end
#
    to_index_models.sort! do |a, b|
        begin
            a.name <=> b.name
        rescue Object
            0
        end
    end
#
    begin
        to_index_models.uniq!
    rescue Object
    end
#
    to_index_models.each do |model|
        begin
            model.create_indexes
            puts "indexed: #{ model }"
        rescue Object => e
            warn "failed on: #{ model }#create_indexes"
        end
    end
end
end
```

This was taken from http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongoid/12akaq1na7/equivalent-of-create-indexes-rake-task-in-non-rails-environment#20121106gzwpoiifznpdxa3ugtzdvjgplq

And my mongoid.yml file is a basic connection to localhost file:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

But whenever I am trying to run the rake task as:

```
rake db:create_indexes[development]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.       0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:171:in `spec'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in       `establish_connection'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:39:in        `database='
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1208:in `set'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.4/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:33:in        `database_file='
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1208:in `set'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1982:in `block (2 levels) in      delegate'
/Users/harshsingh/Documents/Codes/mogreet-requestbin/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/harshsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Mongoid and ActiveRecord?

Comment: I was not sure of the idea about how will be able to do custom create_indexes in the sinatra using Mongoid.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but as far as I know Mongoid is something you use *instead* of activerecord, not *with* activerecord.

Comment: take a look at this sample app https://github.com/mzaragoza/shipstickschalenge/blob/master/Gemfile